# Como copiar o conteúdo html gerado dentro do ng-repeat em uma textarea?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="(keyC, column) in columns.form" ng-model="columns.form"  >
  <div class="well">
     <p><strong>BLOCO {{ keyC }}</strong></p>
      <div ng-repeat="(keyP, p) in column.perguntas" ng-model="column.perguntas"  >
          <formulario  data="p" ></formulario>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como copiar o conteúdo que foi gerado no DOM para uma `textarea`?
Na verdade deve ser gerado somente algumas coisas dentro da `textarea`:

```
<div class="well">
   <p><strong>BLOCO 0</strong></p>
   <div class="alert alert-danger">88888</div>         
</div>
<div class="well">
   <p><strong>BLOCO 1</strong></p>
   <div class="alert alert-danger">123123123</div>         
</div>
```

Jsfiddle para melhor explicação:
https://jsfiddle.net/na4t6k57/

tentei fazer isso, mas creio que está totalmente errado:

```
<div ng-init="html = ''"></div>
<div ng-repeat="(keyC, column) in columns.form" ng-model="columns.form"  >
  {{ html += '<div class="well">' }}
    {{ html += '<p><strong>BLOCO' + keyC '</strong></p>' }} 
      <div ng-repeat="(keyP, p) in column.perguntas" ng-model="column.perguntas"  >
          {{ html += '<formulario  data="p" ></formulario>' }} 
      </div>
  {{ html += '</div>' }}
</div>

<textarea ng-model="html"></textarea>
```

Comment: Porquê você colocou um ng-model na div ?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui obter o html através do JQuery Lite que vem embutido no Angular.
Coloquei um **id** no ng-repeat inicial e criei um botão com a função de colocar o html no model segue link do meu JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/unahk45a/

```
$scope.seta=function(){
    $scope.textarea = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('#id')).html();
}
```

Explicação:

`document.querySelectorAll()` seletor nativo do Javascript

`angular.element()` vai transformar o objeto passado em um objeto jquery lite (se você tiver colocado a dependência do JQuery no seu projeto será um objeto JQuery)

`html()` metódo Jquery que retorna o conteúdo html do objeto JQuery

Comment: Tem ainda mais 1 desafio que é fazer um watch para isto ou rodar a função seta() depois que o ng-repeat ter rodado.